# ST_Transform result value of PostGIS is different

Tags: postgis

PostGIS is installed on each of the two servers.
I run the following query on one server to get the following results:

- query

```
select st_astext(st_transform(
      ST_GeomFromWKB('01010000203B1400001CB72B9CCEC62D41C14E439A5EBF3D41'::geometry, 5179),3857))
```

- result1

```
POINT(14162637.4168507 4515322.6138588)
```

and then I ran the same query on the other server and got the following results

- result2

```
POINT(14162637.4168507 4489271.07636558)
```

The two servers' spatial_ref_sys tables had the same definitions for 5179 and 3857, respectively.
I do not know why two result values have the same x value but different y values

result1 server version is ...

```
POSTGIS="2.1.2 r12389" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.6" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

result2 server version is ...

```
POSTGIS="2.4.5dev r16619" PGSQL="96" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6" PROJ="Rel. 5.0.0, March 1st, 2018" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.13.99" RASTER
```

is there a bug in a particular version?

epsg:5179 definition

```
5179    EPSG    5179    PROJCS["Korea 2000 / Unified CS",GEOGCS["Korea 2000",DATUM["Geocentric_datum_of_Korea",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6737"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4737"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",38],PARAMETER["central_meridian",127.5],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",1000000],PARAMETER["false_northing",2000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","5179"]] +proj=tmerc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=127.5 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=2000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: Paste the output of `SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();` in both servers

Comment: please use the edit button to add your information to the question

Comment: Please run this on both databases `select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=5179;`

Comment: maybe this [bug](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/834)